# Why am I not able to compile this assembly code?

Tags: arm, programming, assembly, stm32f4, cortex-m4

When assembling the code, I get the error : fpu.s(13): error: A1240E: Immediate value cannot be used with this operation

```
AREA PGRM, CODE, READONLY
ENTRY
EXPORT __main
__main
    LDR R0,=0XE000ED88
    LDR R1,[R0]
    ORR R1,R1,#(0xF << 20)
    STR R1,[R0]
    dsb



    VMOV.F32 S7, #0x419c0000
    VMOV.F32 S8, #0X41B40000
    VADD.F32 S9,S7,S8

LOOP    B LOOP
    END
```

Comment: I consider this question as off-topic, because is solely programming related, no matter what platform is used.

Comment: Be consistent with your hexadecimal numbers. Use #0xFFFFFFFF instead of sometimes using #0XFFFFFFFF. You can confuse the compiler with being inconsistent.

Comment: @Sparky256, the compiler will get confused? I thought it either rejects completely or accepts syntax for constants and those look legal enough.

Answer (score 2):

In VMOV, the F32 format expects the following argument as immediate value:

> Any number that can be expressed as \$\pm n \times 2^{–r}\$, where n and r are
>   integers, 16 <= n <= 31, 0 <= r <= 7.

You have the following immediate values:

$$
\text{0x}419C0000 = 4199\times2^{18} \\
n = 4199 \quad r = -18
$$
and
$$
\text{0x}41B40000 = 4205\times2^{18} \\
n = 4205\quad r = -18
$$

In both instructions, the immediate values are clearly out of the expected range. You should scale these parameters beforehand.

Comment: This was my thought too, but checking the user guide for the cortex-m4 this restriction isn't listed. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDJBCJG.html

Comment: @Colin__s Not sure I follow, the same description of value ranges is there in the link you presented. Do you mean to say the assembler should turn a blind eye to this?

Comment: please check the link again, I had the wrong thing on my clipboard when I first commented. The cortex m4 manual states "Restrictions
There are no restrictions."

Comment: @Colin__s Indeed, this seems the case. If value ranges are not to blame, my next guess would be wrong target configuration.

Comment: @Vincente I have used ARMCM4_FP simulated processor core.

Comment: @Colin__s That 'no restrictions' applies to when, not to the number of bits used for encoding an immediate value.